# Prerequisite to start learning Topological K-Theory

Tags: reference-request, topological-k-theory, k-theory

Wanted to start learning K-theory to see if it is suitable for a undergraduate thesis (from an algebraic-topological view).
For reference, I only know [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) (mostly because I've read his book about algebraic-topology) 
But I wanted to know what are the necessary prerequisite to achieve a good level of understanding of the subject. I've had courses in algebraic topology, commutative algebra, group theory... All of them at undergraduate level

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some differential geometry would help a lot (tangent bundles etc), but otherwise I think you're good.

Comment: Yeah I'm following a course about classical diff. Geom, but we are studying now some basics notion of abstract diff geom,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did pretty much what you're proposing when I was an undergrad, and with precisely that level of background.  I had not taken differential geometry at that point, so it's not totally necessary; however, I do think that I could have used a little more exposure to geometric ideas, since Atiyah's book (said to be excellent) was entirely lost on me for this reason.