# Linear algebra and K-theory

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, k-theory

I am looking for a reference where I can learn both linear algebra, and K-theory. Does such a reference exist?

Comment: Yes, you can simply add any reference for linear algebra with one on K-theory. This site has many references, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592540/prerequisite-to-start-learning-topological-k-theory). Both subjects are different, so usually they are not in the same book.